# Webservice client in JAVA with CFX3.0, works in eclipse not as exported JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, webservice-client

I am using CFX3.0.1 to create a webService-client in JAVA using Eclipse.
The client works in eclipse. I run it as a JAVA application. But when I export as a runnable JAR, it fails with following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:99)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.featuretracking.wsclient.Service1.<init>(Service1.java:43)
    at org.featuretracking.wsclient.IService1_BasicHttpBindingIService1_Client.main(IService1_BasicHttpBindingIService1_Client.java:50)
```

I am using default build chain in Eclipse, no Maven.
Can some one please tell me how I can make the JAR work.